# Why is echo faster than print?

Tags: php, comparison, performance, printing, echo

In **PHP**, why is [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) faster than [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)?

They do the same thing... Why is one faster than the other?

Do they do ***exactly*** the same thing?

Comment: Aren't they just aliases of one another? Where did you get the idea that the one is faster than the other?

Comment: A good answer of Fabien Potencier creator of Symfony http://fabien.potencier.org/article/8/print-vs-echo-which-one-is-faster

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`echo` and `print` are virtually (not technically) the same thing. The (pretty much only) difference between the two is that `print` will return the integer `1`, whereas `echo` returns nothing. Keep in mind that neither is actually a function, but rather language constructs. `echo` allows you to pass multiple strings when using it as if it were a function (e.g., `echo($var1, $var2, $var3)`).

`echo` can also be shorthanded by using the syntax `<?= $var1; ?>` (in place of `<?php echo $var1; ?>`).

As far as which is faster, there are many online resources that attempt to answer that question. [PHP Benchmark](http://www.phpbench.com/) concludes that "[i]n reality the echo and print functions serve the exact purpose and therefore in the backend the exact same code applies. The one small thing to notice is that when using a comma to separate items whilst using the echo function, items run slightly faster."

It will really come down to your preference, since the differences in speed (whatever they actually are) are negligible.

Comment: I had wrote an article about this and I have done a benchmar using [VLD](http://derickrethans.nl/projects.html#vld), please check: [http://rakesh.sankar-b.com/2011/01/12/echo-print-which-is-fast-php/](http://rakesh.sankar-b.com/2011/01/12/echo-print-which-is-fast-php/)

Answer (score 2):

Print always returns 1, which is also probably why it's slower

Answer (score 1):

Print has a return value, this is the only difference.

The speed difference (if any) is so miniscule that it's not worth the effort thinking about micro optimisations like this, and it's absolutely not worth updating any old code to switch prints to echos. There are much better ways to speed up your site, if this is your goal.

Answer (score 0):

As my experience and knowledge, **You are wrong**. `print` is faster than `echo` in the loops autobahn and hypertexts.

### Which is faster?

I'm implementing a test that shows the difference between `print` and `echo`.

```
$start = microtime(1);
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
    echo "Hello world!";

echo "echo time: " . round(microtime(1) - $start, 5);

$start = microtime(1);
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
    print "Hello world!";

echo "print time: " . round(microtime(1) - $start, 5);
```

result:

```
echo time: .09
print time: .04
```

Another reference is [phpbench](http://www.phpbench.com/) that shows this fact.

### Comparision

Now its time to investigate that why `print` is faster than `echo`. When you are using loops, of course, php checks if echo has multiple values to print or not, but always print can take only one parameter and it's not needed to be checked in loops. also when there are multiple values for echo bad things come through, like converting them to string and streaming them, I do believe that in huge hypertexts these problem come through too because you are forcing php to process before printing. But in small jobs like printing, only a small string echo I good (if you consider concatenations) because it doesn't return anything like print.